# How to trigger condition to only the listed names

Tags: javascript

I currently created this condition that only works for the listed **userName** from the **data.uniqueId**. Without the condition, it works to all names from the **data.uniqueId**. My purpose is so I could trigger the **addContent** to some names of my choice only, those that I will put the list.

```
let userName = data.uniqueId;

if(userName == "name1"){
        addContent(
            `<img src="${userAvatar}" style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius: 50%;"/>&nbsp;<span class="hostMessage">Host</span>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">${userName}</span>: ${message}`
            );
}
```

The code I have now is working but only for **name1**, I don't know how to do the code if I want to have more than 1 **userName** in the list.

Could anyone help me with this? I would appreciate it if you could come up with a way that's easier for me to add more names to the list in the future, maybe a different .js file just for the name list and then call to a different .js file where I currently have the code above.

Otherwise, any method that works should be fine enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is data, is it an array or an object? share full info about your code. and put it in a snippet and make sure it runs properly to show the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array with the possible names

```
const names = ["name1", "name2", ...]
```

and then in the condition do a

```
if(names.includes(userName)){...
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use an array (a list of elements) which has a method called `includes(element)` which will return true if the element is present on the list. Something like this:

```js
let userNames = ["name1","name2","name3"];

if(userNames.include("name1")){ // will return true, thus entering the if
        addContent(
            `<img src="${userAvatar}" style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius: 50%;"/>&nbsp;<span class="hostMessage">Host</span>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">${userName}</span>: ${message}`
            );
}
```

more information about includes here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely clear on what you want but this might be helpful.

Declare or build an array of names:

```
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charles"];
```

if the name you want to test is:

```
const userName = "Bob";
```

You can then do an if statement like this:

```
if (names.includes(userName)) {
   // do whatever 
}
```

Note that this test is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that data is an array. then you can use `for each` to loop through all the elements in it

```
let userName = data.uniqueId;

data.forEach(user => {

    if(user.uniqueId == "name1"){
        addContent(
            `<img src="${userAvatar}" style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius: 50%;"/>&nbsp;<span class="hostMessage">Host</span>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">${userName}</span>: ${message}`
            );
    }
    
});
```